# How can I add spans to characters inside a string that currently don't have <span> elements?

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings that look like this:

```
 "<span>X</span>間違<span>う</span><span>ABCDE</span>"
```

How can I add spans to the elements that do not have spans already so the string looks like this:

```
 "<span>X</span><span>間</span><span>違</span><span>う</span><span>ABCDE</span>"
```

Is this something that I can do with Regex?

Example 2 source

```
"<span>X</span>A<span>う</span>ABC<span>Y</span>"
```

Example 2 result

```
"<span>X</span><span>A</span><span>う</span><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span><span>Y</span>"
```

Example 3 source:

```
"間違<span>う</span>"
```

Example 3 result:

```
"<span>間</span><span>違</span><span>う</span>
```

Example 4 source:

```
"<span>う</span>間違"
```

Example 4 result:

```
"<span>う</span><span>間</span><span>違</span>"
```

Please note, it's only the characters that do not have a span that I need to add spans to each of. I hope it makes sense. So in the first case "ABCDE" needs to stay as "ABCDE".

Comment: Did you try `Regex.Replace`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I have used Regex.Replace before for simple needs but this case I am not sure how I can use it because I need each character inside of </span>間違<span> to be surrounded by a new span. Not just the "間違". Note that these could be different characters also.

Comment: It is easier than that. You need to wrap each char outside of `<span>[^<]*</span>` with span tags.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Can you give an example as an answer. I tried the other two solutions but both have some problems and don't work for the data that I have.

Comment: Why is the result for  `"間違<span>う</span>" ` not `<span>間違</span><span>う</span>`?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the requirement I've been given and I confirmed that was the case. Each character not in a span needs to be place in its own span. Not combined  into one span.

Comment: A universal but slightly inefficient solution is `Regex.Replace(text, @"(?s)(<span(?:\s+[^>]*)?>.*?</span>)|\P{M}\p{M}*", x => x.Groups[1].Success ? x.Groups[1].Value : $"<span>{x.Value}</span>")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew -  could you add this as an answer so I can review and accept if it works.  No problem if it's inefficient as the code will only execute once every few seconds for  10,000  times in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string you process is not actually HTML and just plain text with non-nested `span` tags, the problem can be solved with regex while treating `<span>` and `</span>` as starting and ending delimiters.

You may capture and keep the text between two tags and match any other char in other contexts:

```
var pattern = @"(?s)(<span(?:\s+[^>]*)?>.*?</span>)|\P{M}\p{M}*";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, x => 
    x.Groups[1].Success ? x.Groups[1].Value : $"<span>{x.Value}</span>");
```

The pattern will become more efficient if you replace `.*?</span>` with `[^<]*(?:<(?!</span>)[^<]*)*`:

```
var pattern = @"(<span(?:\s+[^>]*)?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/span>)[^<]*)*</span>)|\P{M}\p{M}*";
```

**Details**

- `(<span(?:\s+[^>]*)?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/span>)[^<]*)*</span>)` - Group 1: matches and captures a

  - `<span` - a literal substring, then
  - `(?:\s+[^>]*)?>` - an optional 1+ whitespaces followed with 0+ chars other than `>`
  - `[^<]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` followed with
  - `(?:<(?!/span>)[^<]*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of `<` not followed with `/span>` and then any 0+ chars other than `<` and then
  - `</span>` - `</span>` text
- `|` - or
- `\P{M}\p{M}*` - any Unicode grapheme.

The `x.Groups[1].Success ? x.Groups[1].Value : $"<span>{x.Value}</span>")` logic reverts Group 1 value if Group 1 participated in the match, else, wraps the matched char with span tags.

Answer (score 1):

(Updated in the light of the new examples)

Regex will fail for html. Please see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/)

## I've been warned, I want to use regex for html

Something like this could do the job.

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(^|</span>)(.*?)(<span>|$)", "$1<span>$2</span>$3");
```

Please note that this will not split words are not wrapped in spans; it will just wrap them in spans. Since words that are already wrapped in spans are not split this seems reasonable.

---

## Test

```
string input = "間違<span>う</span>X<span>ABC</span>Y<span>DEF</span>GHI";

Console.WriteLine(input);
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, "(^|</span>)(.*?)(<span>|$)", "$1<span>$2</span>$3");

Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

```
間違<span>う</span>X<span>ABC</span>Y<span>DEF</span>GHI
<span>間違</span><span>う</span><span>X</span><span>ABC</span><span>Y</span><span>DEF</span><span>GHI</span>
```

Comment: I think there are some ")" missing.  Can you confirm.

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried this with "間違<span>う</span>" and it doesn't see the first two characters.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer to cover for this case as well

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I should have included the case where strings could appear at the start and end also.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the tags to get the plain text, then add the tags to each character.

Example :

```
    var span = "<span>X</span>間違<span>う</span><span>Y</span>";

    var plain = span.Replace("<span>", "").Replace("</span>", "").Trim();

    var sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty); 

    for(int x =0; x < plain.Length; x++)
    {
        sb.Append($"<span>{plain[x]}</span>");

    }
```

Comment: The problem here is that only those  characters not in spans need to have spans added to them.

Comment: Yeah, I fell for the same :) `ABC` is not mean to be split.

Comment: @Alan2 I think I've got what you want, so I'll update it after work today.